# how to pass arguments in codeigniter php controller functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi friends i have this function to show all articles, i am writing this function again and again for different categories, because codeigniter arguments are related to url how do i pass arguments so that i can reuse this function ?

This is my controller function to show all news.

```
function all_news(){

    //do some pagination
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/news/all_news';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('articles')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 7;
    //some css for pagination
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    //initialize pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    //end pagination

    $data['title'] =" All News";

    //for pagination
    $data['query']= $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $data['query'] =   $this->db->get('articles',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('main/all_news');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving much of your controller logic into a model method.  Then you'll be able send arguments to this method which will return back database results to your controller based on the arguments you send to the method.

Answer (score 0):

http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up

The segment numbers would be this:

1-news
2-local
3-metro
4-crime_is_up

```
 $product_id = $this->uri->segment(3);//metro
```

full info https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html